# get a file from a different branch on git

Tags: git, version-control

I am using Git. I am working on branch-A with uncommitted changes which i do not want to commit now. Lets us say there is a file with name new_file. I want to overwrite the new_file of the branch-A with the  new_file of branch-B's history(i.e. not the latest version of new_file on branch-B)

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout B~N -- new_file
```

Where B is the branch and N is the number of revisions back in branch-B's history you want to go.

For example:

```
git checkout B~10 -- new_file
```

will checkout new_file from 10 commits back in the history of branch B.

Or if you have the hash just

```
git checkout <hash> -- new_file
```

for example:

```
git checkout 6cdd6ef37 -- new_file
```

Comment: is there a way to get the file by using the hash of the commit instead of the number of revisions i need to go back

Comment: @salsabear Hashes and branch names are interchangeable in this context. I updated the answer above.